# Getting value in ZK by passing from java

Tags: java, spreadsheet, zk

I could not take the value that I pass from JAVA code in ZK Spreadsheet (http://www.zkoss.org) file.

Here are what I am doing:

- In java side I call the .zul file

  ```
  String filenames = "test.txt";
  htmlPane.setContentsURL("preview.zul?filename=" + filename);
  ```
- In preview.zul file

  < zk >
    < zscript >< ![CDATA[
  System.out.println(execution.getArg().get("filename"));
  ]] >< /zscript >
  < zk >

The the result is NUll

Could you help how to write the correct script?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I think you have the same issue as stated in ZKOSS.org forum: http://www.zkoss.org/forum/listComment/6098

It might work with the code:

```
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">
<window id="win">
    <zscript>

        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions;

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) Executions.getCurrent().getNativeRequest();
        String info = request.getParameter("name");

    </zscript>

    <caption id="caption">${info}</caption>

   </window>
</zk>
```

Please test and see.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong commad.
Args are user set values what you want to use are params.
mtrs solution should work, but is not nessessary cos zk got an implicit object param.
Have a look at [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/EL_Expressions/Implicit_Objects/param).
And for Java side use:

```
String filename = Executions.getCurrent().getParameter("filename");
```

Comment: Both solution are fine. Thanks so much